# Multiple "upstream" files in one github repo

Tags: github, repository

I've repos with various configuration files, like `.vimrc`, `_vimrc` (for windows), or `.bashrc`. I'd like to create one repo that holds all of them, so I can easily set up my environment on clean machines. I'd like linux / windows specific files to be in different branches (?), so that cloning on linux would not download windows files.

How do I do that, assuming all existing repos are on github and the resulting repo should be on github too?

Is there a way to force git to just download files from a branch and save them in a directory, without creating a local repo? For `.bashrc` it'd be faster to just download and save to `~`, instead of cloning and then copying that file to home dir.

Maybe something like dropbox would be better for this?